# Parse JSON to a flat file in Python

Tags: python, json

I would like to read a JSON format file where key is not same always and convert it into a flat file for further processing. I tried find a solution for this, but nothing worked.

Here is the sample JSON data.

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (5min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
        "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-04-15 13:05:00",
        "4. Interval": "5min",
        "5. Output Size": "Compact",
        "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (5min)": {
        "2019-04-15 13:05:00": {
            "1. open": "120.8250",
            "2. high": "120.9400",
            "3. low": "120.7800",
            "4. close": "120.9275",
            "5. volume": "152975"
        },
        "2019-04-15 13:00:00": {
            "1. open": "120.8900",
            "2. high": "120.8900",
            "3. low": "120.8000",
            "4. close": "120.8250",
            "5. volume": "156065"
        },
        "2019-04-15 12:55:00": {
            "1. open": "120.8600",
            "2. high": "120.9000",
            "3. low": "120.8450",
            "4. close": "120.8950",
            "5. volume": "53450"
        },
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert this to below format

```
2019-04-15 13:05:00,120.8250,120.9400,120.7800,120.9275,152975
2019-04-15 13:00:00,120.8900,120.8900,120.8000,120.8250,156065
2019-04-15 12:55:00,120.8600,120.9000,120.8450,120.8950,53450
```

I tried something like below.

```
url = URL from where data is coming in JSON format.
response = requests.get(url, headers=header, cookies=cookies)
dic = json.loads(response.content)
len_of_timeseries = len(dic["Time Series (1min)"])
key_len = {}
for k in dic["Time Series (1min)"]:
  print (dic["Time Series (1min)"][k])
f = open(symbolFile,"w") 
f.write(write the file here)
f.close
```

Above print statement is print details like below. It's not reading date field at all.

```
{'1. open': '11689.7998', '2. high': '11690.6504', '3. low': '11689.3496', '4. close': '11689.5996', '5. volume': '0'}
{'1. open': '11687.2500', '2. high': '11690.2002', '3. low': '11686.6504', '4. close': '11689.3496', '5. volume': '0'}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: you need `for` loop inside existing `for` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The k value in your for loop contains the date you are looking for:

```
for k in dic["Time Series (1min)"]:
    print (dic["Time Series (1min)"][k])
    print(k) # this will print the date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dic = {
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (5min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
        "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-04-15 13:05:00",
        "4. Interval": "5min",
        "5. Output Size": "Compact",
        "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (5min)": {
        "2019-04-15 13:05:00": {
            "1. open": "120.8250",
            "2. high": "120.9400",
            "3. low": "120.7800",
            "4. close": "120.9275",
            "5. volume": "152975"
        },
        "2019-04-15 13:00:00": {
            "1. open": "120.8900",
            "2. high": "120.8900",
            "3. low": "120.8000",
            "4. close": "120.8250",
            "5. volume": "156065"
        },
        "2019-04-15 12:55:00": {
            "1. open": "120.8600",
            "2. high": "120.9000",
            "3. low": "120.8450",
            "4. close": "120.8950",
            "5. volume": "53450"
        },
    }
}
```

.

```
items = dic["Time Series (5min)"]

for dt, v in items.items():
    row = [dt] # date time
    row += v.values()
    print(','.join(row))
```

Result

```
2019-04-15 13:05:00,120.8250,120.9400,120.7800,120.9275,152975
2019-04-15 13:00:00,120.8900,120.8900,120.8000,120.8250,156065
2019-04-15 12:55:00,120.8600,120.9000,120.8450,120.8950,53450
```

But it may not respect order in row.
If you know keys `"1. open"`, `"2. high"`, etc. then it could be better to use them to keep order.

```
for dt, v in items.items():
    row = [dt, v["1. open"], v["2. high"], v["3. low"], v["4. close"], v["5. volume"]]
    print(','.join(row))
```